# Getting an error when I try to render the posts of users I follow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have a page that posts the statuses of users I follow. I'm new to rails and this error is killing me. I can give anything else if its needed

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    @hub_items = current_user.hub.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
def hub
  Timeline.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

timeline.rb

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
      user_id: user.id)
end
```

And this is the error trace.

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 14:11:28 -0700
>   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
>     User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 257ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for Timeline:Class):
>
> ```
> app/models/timeline.rb:47:in `from_users_followed_by'
> app/models/user.rb:24:in `hub'
> app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
> ```
>
> Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.0ms)
>     Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
>     Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (5.0ms)
>     Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (646.0ms)

Comment: Seems like your `Timeline` class in not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, so the `.where` method is not present. Guess you're wanting to do a `Post.where(...)`.

Comment: Awesome, that helped. Also, if you don't mind, could you tell me how you came to that? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm is right. The only reason you dont have `where` on your model is becuase its not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Timeline
  def self.do_something
    where(...) # is equivalent to self.where(...)
    # The `where` method should in your app be defined by ActiveRecord, 
    # and present in those classes that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base
    # (`class Post < ActiveRecord::Base; end). Since Timeline is no class
    # backed by a database table, you will want to load `Post.where(...)
    # or SomeModel.where(...) to display in your timeline.
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way for `self.from_users_followed_by` to be written to **not** inherit from ActiveRecord?

Comment: Could I possibly _scope_ the followed users' ids in my user model or  _join_ them together in my hub method?

Answer (score 0):

you could also use scopes with params http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments